# JSON.ENCODE is splitting variable with space into multiple variables

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a asp.net mvc4 application and I am serializing a c# object (with Razor) using JSON.Encode, inside the view. What happens is, parts that have a space in it, the JSON.ENCODE will try to translate it to mulitple variables per space.

example.  Part.Name = "A B C"
JSON Encode will produce: {"Name":"A" B="" C=""}

How can I prevent this?

Using Razor, 
Code:

```
             foreach (Transaction transaction in Model)
             {
                <tr value= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(transaction)) onclick="commitTRValuesToForm(this)">
                <td>@transactionLite.system</td>
                <td>@FormattingUtility.DecimalTo12HR(transactionLite.Time)</td>
                <td>@transactionLite.Intials</td>

             }
```

ajax call:

```
function commitTRValuesToForm(rowInstance)
{
    var jsonString = $(rowInstance).attr('value');

             var src = '@Url.Action("JsonResultForm", "Home", new { area = "Part" })'
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: src,
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: jsonString,
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 success: function (data) {
                     //do stuff
                 }
             });
};
```

Comment: You're doing something completely wrong.  Show us your code.

Comment: You need double quotes around that string.

Comment: What are you attempting to do here? `value` is not a valid html attribute for a `<tr>` element. And it needs to be quoted in anycase

Comment: I am trying to store the encoded object, so when the table is clicked on that row, I can pass the encoded value to pass along with ajax to server side code. I will post my function with ajax.. This works fine when there isn't spaces inside a part name.

Comment: Nothing is being edited at all so why are you generating all that extra html in the view and then sending it all back again unchanged. Just include the ID of the `transaction` object - `<tr data-id="@transaction.ID">...` and `$('tr').click(function() { $.post('@Url.Action(...)', { id: $(this).data('id'), function(data) { // do stuff}); });` to post back the ID

Comment: Why are you passing the entire object as json? You obviously have the object server side since that's where you're serializing it to json only to pass it back to yourself after round tripping to the client. It's a very convoluted way to do this, why not just put the part id in the row and when they click the row pass the id to the server and lookup the rest of the part details at that point?  (posted this at the same time as ^ Stephen Muecke)

Comment: Because these are transactions which don't get edited, so I figured it would be easier since the object wasn't very big to just serialize it and open it up on server and use the information needed rather than making another database call to fill it, but I could rethink it to circumvent this. But, in the event I did need to serialize the object and use it this way, I am still trying to understand why JSON.ENCODE is behaving this way, and what to do to fix it.

Comment: Because you need to quote it - `<tr value="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(transaction))" ... >` but that is not the correct way to go about in any case. If you really want to waste resources, then assign the model to a javascript variable - `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)` and then based on the index of the clicked row, get the corresponding object from the collection - `var rowIndex = $(this).index(); var transaction = model[rowIndex];`

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I will make adjustments to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Stephen suggestions,

```
  <tr value= '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(transaction))' onclick="commitTRValuesToForm(this)">
```

instead of:

```
  <tr value= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(transaction)) onclick="commitTRValuesToForm(this)">
```

resolved the issues JSON.ENCODE was giving me.

Update:
Also, it was said that value is an illegal attribute, but the alternative was never mentioned; which I later stumbled upon to be: data-value.. Using data value is better because it's not illegal and it will bring the type as well. So if I wanted to pass an array like so,

```
<tr  value='["val1","val2"]' onclick="addToSelectedList(this)">
```

when retrieved, the value would be one string value as "[val1,val2]"

now instead,

```
<tr  data-value='["val1","val2"]' onclick="addToSelectedList(this)">
```

would return the value as an array, with 2 elements [0]=val1 and [1]=val2

Comment: This has nothing to do with `JSON.Encode`; you were generating illegal HTML.

Comment: I am more proficient with backend code. I am still learning front end stuff. What exactly was happening? Why does it work only with single but not double, and why did it work fine without any quotes (no errors thrown) but multiple spaces made things go awry?

Comment: Compare "View Source" (which shows what your server sent) to the DOM inspector (which shows how the browser parsed it).

Comment: What is the rule of thumb then for using double vs single quotes, as using double quotes around @html.Raw(Json.Encode()) resulted in the same issue as not using any, but single quotes worked fine.

Comment: You should use double-quotes, but you should HTML-escape your strings so that they don't have double-quotes inside (this prevents this bug and XSS holes).  Don't call `Html.Raw()`.